Arithmetic inside SQL Query
I am trying to do the below:
SELECT strftime('%w', datetime * 1000) from table;

The above does not work, gives me NULL values.
Since I do not require by-second precision, I store timestamps in the database after dividing by 1000.
This is how I store a timestamp in database.
let timeStamp = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

Thus, I need to multiply the datetime field by 1000.
Edit: results of SELECT datetime, datetime * 1000, strftime('%w', datetime * 1000) from table;
datetime    datetime * 1000 strftime('%w', datetime * 1000)
1712498400  1712498400000   NULL
1712497500  1712497500000   NULL
1712500200  1712500200000   NULL
1712501040  1712501040000   NULL
1712499300  1712499300000   NULL
1714185000  1714185000000   NULL
1714148100  1714148100000   NULL


Could you share some simple data, the expected output, and the DDL for the table

Hi - can you also explain why storing data at minute precision would require you to multiply it by 1000?

Since I do not require by-second precision, I store timestamps in the database after dividing by 1000.

Try SELECT datetime, datetime * 1000, strftime('%w', datetime * 1000) from table; And you will see where the null comes from. Is datetime itself null? Is datetime * 1000 null may be because of an type incompatibility or an overflow something? Or is the formatted string null maybe because of an invalid format or a format not applying for a given value or type? This is called debugging and only you can do it because only you have table with data in it.

The common usage of the word "timestamp", in this context, is a datatype supported by an RDBMS. Whether you choose to round a timestamp to date, hour, minute or second doesn't affect the precision with which the value is held in a timestamp column (i.e. 2024-05-07 12:21:45, 2024-05-07 12:21:00, 2024-05-07 12:00:00, 2024-05-07 00:00:00) - so saying that you "store timestamps in the database after dividing by 1000" appears to make no sense - as that would not be a timestamp. Please update your question with the DDL for the table, sample data for that table and the result you want to achieve

I ran SELECT datetime, datetime * 1000, strftime('%w', datetime * 1000) from table; and results are added to question above.

@NickW The only reason, albeit silly, for me to store the timestamp in such a way is merely to save some memory.

You're really not saving anything and you're just making your life harder to use the data. Save your data as timestamps in a column with a timestamp datatype

%w doubles the quotes (") in a string. See: SQLite's Built-in printf(), chapter 2.1. The strftime function works on datetime values, but you are applying it to an integer. It is not clear to me, what you are trying to achieve.
